# Field service in Controller required a single bean, but 3 were found:

Tags: spring-boot

How did the autowire bean with the property matching the bean class name solve the issue? I have two different service classes extends same service
and being injected with different field names. Below is my code snippet

My controller

```java
@RestController
public class OriginalController {
    @Autowired
    private OriginalService service;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/test")
    public void test(){
        service.execute();
    }
}
```

My Services

```java
@Service
public class OriginalService {
    public void execute() {
    }
} 

@Service
public class ChildOne extends OriginalService {
} 

@Service
public class ChildTwo extends OriginalService {
}
```

When I run my application, I get the below error

```
Field service in controller.OriginalController required a single bean, but 3 were found:
    - childOne: defined in file \service\ChildOne.class
    - childTwo: defined in file \service\ChildTwo.class
    - originalService: defined in file \service\OriginalService.class
```

But when I change my controller code like below, the error is gone

```java
@RestController
public class OriginalController {
    @Autowired
    private OriginalService originalService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/test")
    public void test(){
        originalService.execute();
    }
}
```

Can somebody please clarify how this worked in the first place? In case of different classes implementing interface there are ways to solve using @Primary or @Qualifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thats because you have annotated your `ChildOne` and `ChildTwo` with the `@Service` annotation.

Spring will create the `OriginalService` because it as annotated and then it will create your two other that inherit from the `OriginalService`. Spring cant create them because there is already a created singelton `OriginalService` in the context.

Each instance needs its own `OriginalService` but it cant create them because there is already one.

Comment: ok. But the issue was resolved soon after changing the autowire property matching the camelcase of bean class name. What happens internally when we use the autowire property that is not matching with the bean class name?

Comment: if you use the camelcased classname it will try to find that specific bean with that specific classname.

If you dont use the same name as the bean (like in your case just "service") it will try to locate the bean by type and in your case it found 3 different beans that hade the type of OriginalService so spring paniced and crashed because it didnt know which bean to inject.

Comment: Fantastic. I got this now. One final question, in my example without changing the camelcase having i.e "service" as is for  autowire bean property and fix the issue. what are the options available ?

Comment: you can name your beans `@Service("myBean")`